# How to get dates between two dates from MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, date

I want to get dates between two dates from MySQL table

## EXAMPLE

- fromdate(2015-01-01 and so on....),
- todate(2015-01-10...and so on)

are the columns i have to get dates between these two columns.

How to get this dynamically using MySQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a query that use startdate and enddate and displays the date list

```
SELECT @start_date + INTERVAL num DAY dt FROM
(SELECT tth*10000+th*1000+h*100+t*10+u num FROM
(SELECT 0 tth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TTHN,
(SELECT 0 th UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) THN,
(SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) HN,
(SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TN,
(SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) UN) A,
(SELECT '2015-01-01' start_date) B,
(SELECT '2015-01-10' end_date) C
WHERE start_date + INTERVAL num DAY <= end_date
ORDER BY num;
```

Here is the output

```
mysql> SELECT @start_date + INTERVAL num DAY dt FROM
    -> (SELECT tth*10000+th*1000+h*100+t*10+u num FROM
    -> (SELECT 0 tth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TTHN,
    -> (SELECT 0 th UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) THN,
    -> (SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) HN,
    -> (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TN,
    -> (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    -> UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) UN) A,
    -> (SELECT '2015-01-01' start_date) B,
    -> (SELECT '2015-01-10' end_date) C
    -> WHERE start_date + INTERVAL num DAY <= end_date
    -> ORDER BY num;
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2015-01-01 |
| 2015-01-02 |
| 2015-01-03 |
| 2015-01-04 |
| 2015-01-05 |
| 2015-01-06 |
| 2015-01-07 |
| 2015-01-08 |
| 2015-01-09 |
| 2015-01-10 |
+------------+
10 rows in set (0.08 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is how the query works

- `Subquery A` : Numbers from 0 to 99,999
- `Subquery B` : Start Date
- `Subquery C` : End Date
- `dt` : Date generated from Start Date + any number of days from `Subquery A`
- `WHERE start_date + INTERVAL num DAY <= end_date;` : Boundary of the Date List

You could then `LEFT JOIN` this list to your actual MySQL table.

I discussed a similar technique before : [get all dates in the current month](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97773/get-all-dates-in-the-current-month/97810#97810)

In your particular case, if you had `from_date` and `to_date` in a table called `mytable`, the query would go something like this

```
SELECT B.from_date + INTERVAL num DAY dt FROM
(SELECT tth*10000+th*1000+h*100+t*10+u num FROM
(SELECT 0 tth UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TTHN,
(SELECT 0 th UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) THN,
(SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) HN,
(SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) TN,
(SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) UN) A,
mytable B
WHERE B.from_date + INTERVAL num DAY <= B.to_date
ORDER BY num;
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Comment: it is taking more tha an hour to execute the results for 14000 records. is there any another way using while loop or joins for the same scenario?