# Get all dates in the current month report from three table with date wise sum and balance

Tags: mysql, join

I have three seperate table without any foregin key or relations each..
[image: database three table]

I need a Summary like this
[image: should be summary display like this]

Now, what and how will be mysql query.. I am very new web developer... please kindly lets me know details. pleas help me on this issues

refference links :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676653/mysql-query-two-tables-get-data-in-date-wise-or-user-wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach I've used in the past. I think this will help you with the basics. I've only included 2 of the tables, adding the third should help you to understand the answer rather than copy/paste it.

(You'll need to change the first line to add references to sum(Costings), and add a 'union' 'select ... from bank_mobile_costing', in addition to adding a reference 'Costing' column to the 'Investments' and 'Earnings' select statements.)

```
select date,sum(Investments),sum(Earnings),sum(Investments+Earnings) as Balance from
(
select date,amount as 'Investments',0.0 as 'Earnings' from bank_mobile_investments
union
select date,0.0,amount from bank_mobile_earnings 


) mydata 
group by date
order by 1
```

It's worth my noting here that this will NOT display a list of calendar dates in the date column, but rather it displays a complete list of all the dates which exist in your 3 tables; I don't know if that's appropriate to your needs.

On the subject of your running total column at the end, this is a convoluted subject but a quick google search yields the following stack overflow result which gives a couple of methods of doing it, and there are some interesting points raised in the comments about the advantages or drawbacks of the methods.

[Calculate a Running Total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response..
Before posting this problem.. I had try to resolve the problem from 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97773/get-all-dates-in-the-current-month/97810#97810

(solution of RolandoMySQLDBA)

But I did not able to rearrange... It was perfect solution for me.... Can you please refix the Rolando query with my three table.

KIndly appreicate